# getting facebook user country possible?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I only have a simple question. Is getting Facebook user country using graph api possible?
if yes, how? if not, can you give some other suggestions?

I tried different methods how to get country using graph api but sadly all of them failed.

i try this

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20current_location%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid=4&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN 

it seems working, but for only mark zuckerberg account.

Answer (score 0):

Using the signed-request method you will get the country code.

For details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/